# Nodejs connect remote Oracle db

Tags: node.js, oracle, openshift

I have a node.js application that connects to a remote Oracle database. On my local machine, I use node-oracledb to connect to the db and it works well.

I am trying to deploy this node application on OpenShift. However, I am unable to get node-oracledb installed on OpenShift. I believe this is due to the prerequisite of having Oracle InstantClient downloaded and installed which is not an option in OpenShift.

Any ideas on how to get this working on OpenShift?